# change format of list of dictonary in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries and I am trying to reform it by adding few extra keys by clubbing the existing keys, but got stuck.

```
[
  {
    "middlewareName": "Tomcat",
    "middlewareId": 169935,    
    "dbName": "ORACLE",
    "dbId": 169938,  
    "storageId": 169933,
    "storageName": null,
    "applicationName": "payroll",
    "applicationId": 169933,
    "ID": 001
  },
  {
    "middlewareName": "WebSphere",
    "middlewareId": 169936,    
    "dbName": "ORACLE",
    "dbId": 169938,  
    "storageId": 169933,
    "storageName": null,
    "applicationName": "payroll",
    "applicationId": 169933,
    "ID": 8298
  }
]
```

I want this to convert like below format.  Not able to get the logic to manipulate the above format to get the below one.  Need help:

```
[{
  "applicationId": 3276,
  "applicationName": "Payroll",
  "middlewareList": [
    {
      "middlewareId": 12,
      "middlewareName": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "middlewareId": 121,
      "middlewareName": "AYC"
    }
  ],
  "dbList": [
    {
      "dbId": 12,
      "dbName": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "dbId": 121,
      "dbName": "AYC"
    }
  ],
  "storageList": [
    {
      "storageId": 12,
      "storageName": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "storageId": 121,
      "storageName": "AYC"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

How can it be done?

Comment: I don't see "ABC" in the input.  Try and make your input and what you want to be better examples.  Map it out exactly and somebody might be able to help.  I suspect you just need to iterate though and build your new object.

Comment: sorry .... by mistake it came.... actually values for "storageId","storageName", "dbId", "dbName", "middlewareId" and "middlewareName" I need to take from the 1st format and put it into second format